# Whitespaces between chars produces extra bytes

Tags: powershell, char

I want to send chars to a serial port using powershell:

```
PS > [Char[]] $request = 'C','A'
PS > $port.Write($request)
```

But this creates extra whitespace between the characters. Any ideas why?

```
43 20 41
```

20 is the extra byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that powershell is choosing the overload of `Write` which takes a single `string` parameter. In this case it is converting the array to a string before passing it to `Write`. This conversion inserts the extra space:

```
[string]$request  //C A
```

specify the other two parameters to use the right overload:

```
$port.Write($request, 0, $request.length)
```